# How to add a hierarchy to taxons using grails taxonomy plugin?

Tags: grails, plugins, taxonomy

I would like to have some kind of hierarchy inside my taxons I added to my domain class Foo using Grails Taxonomy plugin. http://grails.org/plugin/taxonomy

Example (annotation to build something like a tree):
{A:{A1:{A1I, A1II}, A2:{A2I}}, B:{B1:{B1I}, B2:{B2II}}}

`foo.addToTaxonomy(['A1', 'A2'], "A")
foo.addToTaxonomy(['B1', 'B2'], "B")`

What is the way have children for A1, A2, B1 and B2 too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your taxonomy trees are defined by

> {A:{A1:{A1I, A1II}, A2:{A2I}}, B:{B1:{B1I}, B2:{B2II}}}

and the notation A->A1->A1I describes a path in a tree. In this case, the path is in the A tree from its root (A) to a leaf (A1I).

If you want to add foo to the A->A1->A1I taxonomy, you would use `foo.addTaxonomy(['A', 'A1', 'A1I'])`. The list parameter for the function `addTaxonomy` actually represents a path in a taxonomy tree. The second parameter accepted by `addTaxonomy` is optional and essentially defines the scope for your taxonomy tree. So, if I were to do

```
foo.addTaxonomy(['A', 'A1', 'A1I'], 'scope1')
foo.addTaxonomy(['A', 'A1', 'A1I'], 'scope2')
```

This would place foo in A->A1->A1I in scope1 and in scope2. They're essentially two different trees. You probably don't need this.

Here are some examples related to the tree structure you described in your question:

add to A->A1->A1II

```
foo.addTaxonomy(['A', 'A1', 'A1II'])
```

add to A2->A2I

```
foo.addTaxonomy(['A2', 'A2I'])
```

add to B->B1->B1I

```
foo.addTaxonomy(['B', 'B1', 'B1I'])
```

add to B2->B2I

```
foo.addTaxonomy(['B2', 'B2I'])
```

The 4 examples above create trees rooted at A, A2, B, and B2, respectively.

If you don't want to define the absolute path of the Taxon, you can do something like this:

```
def taxonPath(taxonName) {
    def currentTaxon = Taxon.findByName(taxonName)
    def path = [currentTaxon.name]

    while(currentTaxon.parent) {
        currentTaxon = currentTaxon.parent
        path = [currentTaxon.name] + path
    }

    return path
}

taxonomyService.createTaxonomyPath(['B', 'B2', 'B2I'])
def book = new Book(name:"hacky solution")
book.addToTaxonomy(taxonPath('B2I'))
```

This is equivalent to `book.addToTaxonomy(['B', 'B2', 'B2I'])`. You will also need to `import com.grailsrocks.taxonomy.Taxon` and inject taxonomyService into your artifact, e.g. (`def taxonomyService`) for this to work.

The solution feels a little hacky and inefficient, but it works.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about this one after asking the question. It nearly solves it. But it has a bit of overhead. If there is some category behaviour of A, B, A1, A2, B1 ... I only had to add B2I to foo and it will implicitly have B2 and B as parent category. I will think about it again, read you later!

Comment: It sounds like you'd prefer to create the trees in advance, and then simply add a domain object to one node in a tree. Unfortunately, it looks like the Taxonomy plugin does not support this. I tried `taxonomyService.createTaxonomyPath(['B', 'B2', 'B2I'])`, which creates the tree {B:{B2:{B2I}}}. Then I did `book.addToTaxonomy(['B2I']). This successfully added `book` to the `'B2I'` taxonomy, however `Book.findAllByTaxonomyFamily(['B'])` returned with no results, which means `book` was not added to `'B'` or `'B2'`. You have to fully qualify the path: `book.addToTaxonomy(['B', 'B2', 'B2I'])`

Comment: Looking at your solution brought me some new idea:

foo.addTaxonomy(['A'], 'level0')
foo.addTaxonomy(['A1'], 'level1')
foo.addTaxonomy(['A1I'], 'level2')
foo.addTaxonomy(['B'], 'level0')
foo.addTaxonomy(['B1'], 'level1')
foo.addTaxonomy(['B1I'], 'level2')

So I do have the chance to query by level

Comment: Actually, I came up with a pretty hacky solution. I'll add it to my original response because it will be easier.

Comment: Hmm if you're solution accomplishes what you're looking for, then good. However, you're really just creating several different Taxon lists: level0:['A', 'B'], level1:['A1', 'B1'], level2:['A1I', 'B1I']. At least that's my understanding. It seems the Taxon plugin is not all that intuitive.

Comment: I slept over it once and your solution does solve it. Forget my comment above, it is not the way taxonomy plugin handles it.